dnf download --resolve not downloading dependencies
I'm trying to download an rpm and its dependencies so that I can install it on an offline machine later. I'm starting with an empty directory, and a repoquery confirms that my target has indeed got a dependency. I run a dnf download --resolve, expecting both the target and dependency to be downloaded, only to see that it has ignored dependencies that were already installed on my machine.
[user@localhost gnome]$ ls

[user@localhost gnome]$ sudo repoquery --requires gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
Last metadata expiration check: 1:11:32 ago on Fri 14 Jun 2024 09:31:02 BST.
gnome-shell-extension-common = 3.32.1-38.el8

[user@localhost gnome]$ sudo dnf download --resolve --destdir=. gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
Last metadata expiration check: 1:11:45 ago on Fri 14 Jun 2024 09:31:02 BST.
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-3.32.1-38.el8.noarch.rpm                                           275 kB/s |  51 kB     00:00    

[user@localhost gnome]$ ls
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-3.32.1-38.el8.noarch.rpm


I posted this QA because I spent a long time trying to solve this issue, despite the documentation being so clear, I hope it can be useful to others in a similar predicament. I did not initially realise the dnf download command was actually a plugin, and couldn't find any documentation on the dnf man page.

From https://www.mankier.com/8/dnf5-download

Description
The download command in DNF5 is used for downloading binary and source packages defined in package-spec arguments to the current working directory.
Options
--resolve

Resolve dependencies of specified packages and download missing ones.

--alldeps

To be used together with --resolve, it downloads all dependencies, not skipping the already installed ones.

--destdir=<path>

Set directory used for downloading packages to. Default location is to the current working directory.


Note that this will likely download a lot more packages than you expect, given that it cannot assume your offline machone has even the most basic packages installed already, or that they would be the correct version if they were.
